# Nhibernate transaction exception

Tags: nhibernate

I am using Nhibernate in a session-per-request context.
When I use session.Update and commit or rollback my transaction, I get an ObjectDisposedException.

the stack trace for this exception is:
   at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.CheckNotDisposed()
   at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Rollback()
   at MyService.update(MyItem item) in C:\Projects\MyProject\ItemService.cs:line 121
   at MyController.Edit(Nullable`1 pageId,  MyItem item, FormCollection collection) in C:\Projects\MyProject\ItemController.cs:line 251

Before I perform the update the transaction contains the following properties:
    isActive: true,
    wasCommitted:false,
    wasRollBacked: false

After I performed the update action the properties have the following values:
    isActive: false,
    wasCommitted:true,
    wasRollBacked: false

Why do I get the exception and why do the booleans change without committing ?

I am using the following code to perform this action:

```
using (var tx = SessionManager.CurrentSession.BeginTransaction()) 
           {
               try
               {


                   //perform update
                   wysiwygitemRepository.Update(item);

                   // perform an action that raises an exception (because of null value)
                   pageSettingService.SaveSettings(null, item.Id);

                   tx.Commit();
               }

               catch(Exception)
               {
                  tx.Rollback();   
               }
           }
```

I used fluhmode.none as flushmode, but also tried flushmode.auto

Even if I change the code to the following , I still got the same exception:

```
using (var tx = SessionManager.CurrentSession.BeginTransaction()) 
       {
           try
           {


               //perform update
               SessionManager.CurrentSession.Update(item);



               tx.Commit();
           }

           catch(Exception)
           {
              tx.Rollback();   
           }
       }
```

Comment: Please post the relevant section(s) of code.

Comment: Did you create your own connection, or is NH creating the connection for you?

Comment: How did you configure the FlushMode ?
Did you start a transaction ?

Comment: Do you do anything else in wysiwygitemRepository.Update as just calling session.Update? What are you doing in pageSettingService.SaveSettings?

Comment: You should probably reduce the code to the minimum needed to reproduce the issue. No repositories, just direct session calls. That's much easier to help you, we can't look into your code.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the problem.

I used some nhibernate interceptors which caused the problem.